# How to make a generic test with NUnit (C#)?

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to write a generic test with NUnit for two types as test cases. 
For example:

```
[TestCase(typeof(Class1))]
[TestCase(typeof(Class2))]
```

Is it even possible to use `Generics` as TestCase or something similiar ? I'd like to avoid duplicate test code. That would be possible if I use `Generics` respectively the types as "Setup".

Thanks for your help.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   _repositoryMock.Setup(c => c.GetByPid<CloudMember>(localRoot.Pid)).Returns((CloudMember)null);

   await _cut.Check();

   Assert.IsFalse(localRoot.HasNeighbor);
}
```

I would like to use Generics for `c.GetByPid<CloudMember>`. So use the TestCases like that `c.GetByPid<TCase>`.

The code maybe would look like:

```
    [TestCase(typeof(Class1))]
    [TestCase(typeof(Class2))] 
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
       _repositoryMock.Setup(c => c.GetByPid<T>(localRoot.Pid)).Returns((CloudMember)null);

       await _cut.Check();

       Assert.IsFalse(localRoot.HasNeighbor);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you want to unit test?

Comment: Done @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In NUnit, you can make a `TestFixture` generic and have the fixture constructed with multiple types. It is much easier to explain in code,

```
[TestFixture(typeof(string))]
[TestFixture(typeof(DateTime))]
public class GenericTests<T>
{
    [Test]
    public void GenericTestMethod()
    {
        Assert.Pass($"The type is {typeof(T)}");
    }
}
```

This will create two test fixtures, `GenericTests<DateTime>` and `GenericTests<String>`.

[image]

Documentation is at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute

Comment: Thank your for your answer and re-opening. I wondered why my question was downvoted..

Comment: Your question is a valid question, but the example code should have been simplified, that is probably why it was down voted.